# PyGTK: Modifying GTKTreeView gridline color

Tags: colors, gtk, pygtk, gridlines, gtktreeview

I am trying to change the default color (black) of the gridlines in a GTKTreeView widget. Using gtk+ 2 and latest pygtk. Any help is appreciated - I do hope this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been sitting a while, so I'll take a crack at it. In looking through the PyGTK documentation (which is pretty comprehensive), there does not appear to be a way to set the gridlines. You can, however, hide or show the gridlines ([link](http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/articles/display-grid-lines-in-GtkTreeView---Part-1---liststore.php)), and set the even and odd line colors ([link](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreeview.html), search for "even-row-color")

Here's hoping I missed something, and there is a way to set line color. But, as far as I can tell, there is no way to do this. That may not be the case in the latest update (PyGObject 3).

Comment: On gtk3 this is now possible by setting border-top-color . see: https://source.puri.sm/Librem5/gtk/commit/7b85d1df50f7b34b2057e21088ded8addb4cda65